# Create diagonal border of a cell

Tags: jquery, css, cell, css-tables, diagonal

I wonder if it is even possible creating a table with diagonal border line using css or jquery just like below:

[image]

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything is possible if you fiddle around with it long enough, here's an example using some creative borders and a lot of CSS:

```
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QvEEB/1/)

And another one using CSS3 rotate:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(26.5deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(26.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(26.5deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(26.5deg);
        transform: rotate(26.5deg);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BrcAq/2/)

or you could just use an image as the background for your table.

Comment: Ok, looks good. But in reality this should be used with the text somehow (Room type, Hospitality). + it should properly work with IE browser.

Comment: How to apply this in a table instead of div?

Comment: The point being, there is no easy cross-browser works everywhere way to do this, it will take a lot of work on your part to make it fit your needs. The only easy solution is to use an image as background.

Comment: Thanks adeneo. In the end, I use image for the diagonal line and div with absulute position for Hospitality and Room Type label.

Comment: In your second example, how did you calculate position after rotation? I mean Line position is `top: 190px;  left: 33px;` .

Comment: @gabbler - three years later, I'm not really sure, can't remember, but I'm guessing it was just trial and error.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks, I tried to find an equation to do it but failed, I set anchor point to zero, and rotate a thin line instead of a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Officially a table cannot have diagonal borders but with little CSS tricks you can make it appear so, 
here's the code..

```
.borderdraw {
position:fixed;
    border-style:solid;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    width:0;
    z-index:-1;

}

table td
    { 
        width:60px; 
            max-height:55px; 
        border:1px solid #000;
    }

.tag1{ z-index:9999;position:absolute;top:40px; }

.tag2 { z-index:9999;position:absolute;left:40px; }

.diag { position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
.outerdivslant { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgb(64, 0, 0); border-width: 50px 0px 0px 60px;}
.innerdivslant {position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff; border-width: 49px 0px 0px 59px;}                  
</style>
```

---

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> 
    <div class = "tag1">Tag1</div>
    <div class="tag2">Tag2</div>

        <div style="z-index:-1;">
           <div class="diag">
             <div class="outerdivslant borderdraw">
             </div>

           <div class = "innerdivslant borderdraw">
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the output.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just created that in a hurry, You can always format that according to your needs. That was one of the way's the style could be acheived.

Answer (score 1):

here's an example in table with border and diagonal in css
https://codepen.io/halimarm/pen/rNaPyGR?editors=1100

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: -5px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(14deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(14deg);
  transform: rotate(14deg); 
}

.diagonal {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
.diagonal span.lb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
.diagonal span.rt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td class="diagonal">
      <span class="lb">Rata - Rata</span>
      <span class="rt">Total</span>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: diagonal table border]

Answer (score 0):

table borders can't be diagonal, you just could try to use an element (div) with one border and rotate it (if css3 is ok)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with CSS [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) for diagonal line and CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for positioning internal cells:

```css
td {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(49%, white), color-stop(50%, black), color-stop(51%, white));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, white 49%, black 50%, white 51%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, white 49%, black 50%, white 51%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, white 49%, black 50%, white 51%);
}
td .c1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px,-20px);
        -ms-transform: translate(20px,-20px);
            transform: translate(20px,-20px);
}
td .c2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20px,20px);
        -ms-transform: translate(-20px,20px);
            transform: translate(-20px,20px);
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="c1">Foo</div>
      <div class="c2">Bar</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or solution<sup>[by Peter Krautzberger](https://www.peterkrautzberger.org/0213/)</sup> with CSS [`background: url(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) SVG image for diagonal line and CSS [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for positioning internal cells:

```css
.cell {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' stroke='black' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.cell--topRight {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  text-align: right;
}

.cell--bottomLeft {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class=cell>
      <div class="cell--topRight">Foo</div>
      <div class="cell--bottomLeft">Bar</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```