# css table td triple diagonal split

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is the result that I am going for:

[image: he]

(The three Chinese are 调类, 调值 and 方言点.)

I just need a single `td class` that I can implement in my css table.

I've seen examples using `png`s or other image files, but I'm not looking for an image to load each time the table is loaded.

The answer here is not bad:

[Create diagonal border of a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727675/create-diagonal-border-of-a-cell)

but I just can't get it to do what I want!

my solution so far is just to have a single td like this:

```
                    <td>
                       调类 →
                       </br>调值 ↘
                       </br>方言点 ↓
                    </td>
```

looks kind of ugly though:

[image: ew]

Comment: *"I just need a single td class that I can implement in my css table."* ...yeah, good luck with that! HTML elements are rectangular and although you can fake otherwise it's probably not going to be effective here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your HTML code a bit and use following styles:

```css
.cell-divided {
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 75px;
 border: 1px solid #513F33;
 color: #513F33;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.cell-divided > div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 1em;
 line-height: 1em;
 margin-top: -.5em;
 padding: 0 40px 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 bottom;
 transform-origin: 0 bottom;
}
.cell-divided > div > span {
 display: inline-block;
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(1) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
 transform: rotate(13deg);
 left: -2px;
 top: -1px;
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(1) > span {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-13deg);
 transform: rotate(-13deg);
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
 transform: rotate(24deg);
 border-bottom: 1px solid #513F33;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 margin-top: -1px
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg);
 transform: rotate(38deg);
 left: -4px;
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(3) > span {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg);
 transform: rotate(-38deg);
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(53deg);
 transform: rotate(53deg);
 border-bottom: 1px solid #513F33;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 margin-top: -1px;
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
 transform: rotate(75deg);
 left: -12px;
 top: -30px;
}
.cell-divided > div:nth-child(5) > span {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg);
 transform: rotate(-75deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell-divided">
                <div>
                    <span>调</span>
                    <span>类</span>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <div>
                    <span>调</span>
                    <span>值</span>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <div>
                    <span>方</span>
                    <span>言</span>
                    <span>点</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, you will need to adjust styles to your table.

Also on **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0spxaoj3/)**.

Comment: It comes out like that because you have other styles on you web page. You need to inspect elements and correct styles overriding (as for example text-align). How it should come out is in the code above, so you can adjust code or hire a developer to do it for you (I'm not free). Cheers