# How to draw diagonal lines with SCRIPT in PDF

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf

I'm using laravel-dompdf package for generating pdf.

I could draw a diagonal line using `rotate` of the CSS.
As you can see, my document have a lot of diagonal lines, so I want to draw a line with scripts.

**Controller**

```
public function downloadPDF () {
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('test', [
        'users' => $users //$users is array
    ])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
    return $pdf->download("test.pdf");
}
```

**View(test.blade.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>{{-- Draw diagonal line here --}}</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>TEL</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($users as $key=>$user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user['name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user['tel'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Below is a sample pdf format.
[image]

How can draw diagonal lines with script?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727675/create-diagonal-border-of-a-cell help?

Comment: or otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425574/slanted-diagonal-line-in-html-or-css

Comment: @NicoHaase Some CSS do not work in dompdf.

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Did you try to use any CSS so far?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried. This is something that only people who have used ```laravel-dompdf ``` can feel.

Comment: dompdf should support `rotate` just fine, so "Some CSS do not work in dompdf" might be true, but not relevant here? Show what you tried please. (That said, dompdf is also ancient, it only really supports CSS 2.1 with a small amount of CSS3, and HTML4 instead of HJTML5, which is tech from 20+ years ago).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are right. ```rotate```is working on.As you can see, I want to draw a line with script because my document has a lot of diagonal lines.

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks. ```rotate``` are working on dompdf. As you can see, my document have a lot of diagonal lines, so I want to draw a line with scripts.

Comment: You can't, because you can't "draw lines" in HTML, you have to either create an element and use CSS to make it _look_ like a line (e.g. border and transform) or you create a canvas element and draw a line on _that_ instead. No idea if dompdf supports canvas though, that would be up to you to check.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I found a clue. I will use ```Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF::line()``` in blade.

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it. You haven't shared any CSS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use `line` function of `Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF`class.

As PDF rendering interface, `CPDF` provide to enable php script on blade, using `set_option("enable_php", true)`

**line function**

`line($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color, $width, $style = [])`

**Controller**

```
public function downloadPDF () {
    $pdf = PDF::getDomPDF()->set_option("enable_php", true)->loadView('test', [
        'users' => $users //$users is array
    ])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
    return $pdf->download("test.pdf");
}
```

```
<script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf)) {
        $pdf->page_script('
            $pdf->line(100, 100, 200, 200, array(0,0,0), 0.7);
        ');
    }
</script>
```